# Using PDO in this script

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to rewrite this script using PDO:

Get values from the database

```
mysql_select_db($database_db_FPF, $db_FPF);
$query_rsWorksMenu = "SELECT works.year, GROUP_CONCAT(workstitle.title) as titulos, GROUP_CONCAT(workstitle.id_title) as links FROM works JOIN workstitle ON works.id_year =      workstitle.id_year GROUP BY works.year ORDER BY works.year DESC";
$rsWorksMenu = mysql_query($query_rsWorksMenu, $db_FPF) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsWorksMenu = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsWorksMenu);
```

Show values

```
     <ul>
        <?php do { ?>
        <li><span><?php echo $row_rsWorksMenu['year']; ?></span>
            <ul>
                <?php 
                 $titulos = explode(",", $row_rsWorksMenu['titulos']);
                 $links = explode(",", $row_rsWorksMenu['links']); 
                 foreach(array_combine($links, $titulos) as $link => $titulo){ 
                ?>
                <li><span><a href="works.php?id=<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $titulo; ?></a></span></li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <?php }while ($row_rsWorksMenu = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsWorksMenu)); ?>
    </ul>
```

What I got so far:

Get the values from the database:

```
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare('SELECT works.year, GROUP_CONCAT(workstitle.title) as titulos, GROUP_CONCAT(workstitle.id_title) as links FROM works JOIN workstitle ON works.id_year = workstitle.id_year GROUP BY works.year ORDER BY works.year DESC');
$stmt2->execute();
$result2 = $stmt2->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Show values

```
        <ul>
        <?php do { ?>
        <li><span><?php echo $result2->year; ?></span>
            <ul>
                <?php 
                 $titulos = explode(",", $result2->titulos);
                 $links = explode(",", $result2->links); 
                 foreach(array_combine($links, $titulos) as $link => $titulo){ 
                ?>
                <li><span><a href="works.php?id=<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $titulo; ?></a></span></li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <?php }while ($row_rsWorksMenu = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsWorksMenu)); ?>
    </ul>
```

The problem is that I don't know what to do with this line:

```
}while ($row_rsWorksMenu = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsWorksMenu));
```

**UPDATE:**

I change my code:

```
$stmt2 = $conn->prepare('...query...');
$stmt2->execute(); 
$result2 = $stmt2->fetchAll();

}while ($row_rsWorksMenu = $stmt2->fetchAll());
```

But nothing happens.

**UPDATE 2**

I try this code:

```
        <?php do { ?>
        <li><span><?php echo $result2->year; ?></span>
            <ul>
                <?php 
                 $titulos = explode(",", $result2->titulos);
                 $links = explode(",", $result2->links); 
                 foreach(array_combine($links, $titulos) as $link => $titulo){ 
                ?>
                <li><span><a href="works.php?id=<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $titulo; ?></a></span></li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <?php }while($result2 = $stmt2->fetch()); ?>
```

And my DOM show the correct numbers of `<li>`. But no values. Why?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be something like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT name, color, calories FROM fruit ORDER BY name';
foreach ($conn->query($sql) as $row) {
    print $row['name'] . "\t";
    print $row['color'] . "\t";
    print $row['calories'] . "\n";
}
```

The PDO `query` method returns a `PDOStatement` which you can iterate directly.

http://www.php.net/manual/de/pdo.query.php

Answer (score 1):

Drop your while loop completely. You also don't need to prepare a statement separately since your query doesn't use any query parameters.

Do this instead:

```
// Get all your DB results in one place
$rsWorksMenu = $conn->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

And later, to display the results:

```
<?php if ($rsWorksMenu):?>
<ul>
<?php     foreach($rsWorksMenu as $r):
             $links_titulos = array_combine(
                explode(",", $r->titulos),
                explode(",", $r->links)
             );
?>
    <li><span><?=h($r->year)?></span>
<?php        if ($links_titulos):?>
        <ul>
<?php            foreach($links_titulos as $link => $titulo):?>
            <li><span><a href="works.php?id=<?=h(urlencode($link))?>"><?=h($titulo)?>a></span></li>
<?php            endforeach // $links_titulos?>
        </ul>
<?php        endif //$links_titulos?>
    </li>
<?php     endforeach // $rsWorksMenu?>
</ul>
<?php endif // $rsWorksMenu?>
```

You should change your sql statement also--it will break if any of your links or titles have commas in them. (`GROUP_CONCAT` is generally a bad idea).

Instead, collect the ungrouped values and group them in a php array yourself, as in the `get_worksmenu` function below:

```
<?php

function get_worksmenu(PDO $db) {
    $rsWorksMenu = array();
    $sql = 'SELECT works.year, workstitle.title AS titulos, workstitle.id_title AS links '
           .'FROM works INNER JOIN workstitle USING (id_year) ORDER BY year DESC';
    // Could this be a single-table query instead?
    //   SELECT id_year AS year, title AS titulos, id_title AS links
    //   FROM workstitle ORDER BY id_year DESC
    $rs = $db->query($sql);
    $rs->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($rs as $r) {
        // calculating url here simplifies your display code
        // and makes it easy to change urls later
        $year = $r['year'];
        $r['url'] = '/works.php?id='.urlencode($r['links']);
        unset($r['year']);
        $result[$year][] = $r;
    }
    $rs->closeCursor();
    return $rsWorksMenu;
}
function h($s) {
    // escape a string for html
    return htmlspecialchars($s, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}


$rsWorksMenu = get_worksmenu($conn);

<?php if ($rsWorksMenu):?>
<ul>
<?php   foreach($rsWorksMenu as $year => $works):?>
  <li><span><?=h($year)?></span>
    <ul>
<?php       foreach($works as $work):?>
        <li><span><a href="<?=h($work['url'])?>"><?=h($work['titulos'])?></a></span></li>
<?php       endforeach //$work?>
    </ul>
<?php   
  </li>
<?php   endforeach // $rsWorksMenu?>
</ul>
<?php endif // $rsWorksMenu?>
```

Comment: +1. Out of interest, I notice that the `<?php` tags in the template file are not indented to the same levels as HTML tags. Is that deliberate, and if so what is the reason for it?

Comment: Just my style. It's easier to see php code when scanning (especially nested blocks) and it doesn't produce excess whitespace in the output.

Comment: Ah, righto. Personally, I like indenting mine as if it were HTML, and using syntax colouring to highlight code blocks, but interesting to see a different approach.